# My starting point is not changing javascript

Tags: javascript, processing

This is written in `p5.js` / processing. My problem is, all the function calls are from the starting point, when it is supposed to update to the old point

```
var aslider, lslider, sslider, newx, newy;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(300,300);
  aslider = createSlider(1,359,17); #angle
  lslider = createSlider(1,50,10); #length
  sslider = createSlider(1,50,20); #amount of side
}

function draw() {
  var angle = aslider.value();
  var length = lslider.value();
  var size = sslider.value();
  var startx = 100;
  var starty = 100;
  var radians = angle * (Math.PI/180);
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    newx =  Math.cos(radians) * length + startx;
    newy = Math.sin(radians) * length + starty;
    line(startx, starty, newx, newy);
    startx = newx; #not changing
    starty = newy; #not changing
  }
}
```

Comment: When is `startx` and `starty` "not updating"? During the iteration of the loop or in subsequent runs of the function (if subsequent function calls it's scoping issue)? Have you set breakpoints on on `startx` and inspected in the debugger during a run? Are you certain `newx`, `newy` do in fact have new values?

Comment: You've to move the declaration of  `startx/y` to an outer scope of the function. Currently you're overriding them every time the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it seems like your `startx` and `starty` variables are not changing is because they are in the `draw()` function. The `draw()` function essentially acts like a `while(true)` loop, and will call itself continuously until you stop running your code. You declare the following inside of `draw()`:

```
var startx = 100;
var starty = 100;
```

This will cause the variables to reset every time draw is called, which is all the time. Thus, the variables will seem like they are not changing. To solve this, simply declare and initially define `startx` and `starty` above `setup()`, which will make those variables global, and prevent this redefining that occurs in `draw()`.